# Problem with fetching Id of the dynamically generated tag using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, ajax

I have the following function to display the id for click event of  tag for which the items are appended dynamically.but when execute the function my alert does not display the id,it pop up saying undefined.please can any one tell where exactly i am going wrong.

This is my function

```
function getmenu()
     {
         $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "JsonWebService.asmx/GetMenus",
             data: "{}",
             contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
             dataType: "xml",

             success:

                 function (results) {

                     $(results).find("Menu").each(function () {
                         var Text = $(this).find("Text").text();
                         var MenuId = $(this).find("MenuId").text();

                         var dmenu = $("#Menudiv");
                         dmenu.append("<td id='" + MenuId + "'><ul>" + Text + "</ul></td>");



                     });


                     $("#Menudiv").children('td').click(function () {

                         alert($(this).children('td').attr('MenuId'));

                     });


                 }
         });

    }
```

This will be my sample xml code generated on ajax call.

```
<ArrayOfMenu><Menu><MenuId>1</MenuId><Text>Books</Text></Menu><Menu><MenuId>2</MenuId><Text>Cd</Text></Menu><Menu><MenuId>3</MenuId><Text>Calendar</Text></Menu></ArrayOfMenu>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line:

```
alert($(this).children('td').attr('MenuId'));
```

to this:

```
alert($(this).attr('id'));
```

That shows the td's id. If you intend to inspect the ul within the td -- and note that you have no li elements within the ul -- you can use "children" as you did above, but you'd need to correct your HTML (<ul><li>...) and change the children selector accordingly... or use find()... depends what you're actually trying to do.